# VBA Runtime Error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to generate emails in a chosen Outlook folder from an Excel macro.

In the code below, 'TestDraft1' works, generating an email in the folder chosen by the user via the user the Namespace.PickFolder method.

However, since I want to generate many emails in the same folder, I need the user to be able to pick the folder just once.  In 'TestDraft2' below, I try to save the folder as an Object, then pass it to the move function. This fails with "Runtime Error 13, Type Mismatch".  The 'folder' variable gives the type "MAPIFolder".

What am I missing here? How is the object I assign to 'folder' different than the one I pass to 'Mailitem.move' ?

**Edit** Note that I'm using late-binding, which is why I'm defining my variables as Objects.  I'd prefer to keep it that way, since I'd like to be able to distribute it without special configuration.  What I really want to know is why the first version succeeds while the second version fails.  Further details: My employer uses Office 2007.

**Edit 2** The problem had nothing to do with what the type of object returned by PickFolder.  It had to do with my misuse of VBA syntax. I've answered the question below, and I'm renaming the it to better address what I was really asking.  Original title was: *Returning an Outlook Folder object in Excel VBA using PickFolder*

```
Sub test()
    Call TestDraft1("test@example.com", "test1") ' succeeds
    Call TestDraft2("test@example.com", "test2") ' fails
End Sub

Sub TestDraft1(recip As String, subj As String)
    Dim OlApp As Object
    Dim NS As Object
    Dim OlMail As Object

    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set NS = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set OlMail = OlApp.createitem(0) 'olMailitem = 0

    OlMail.Subject = subj
    OlMail.Recipients.Add (recip)
    OlMail.Move (NS.PickFolder) ' pass the results of the folder-picker directly
End Sub

Sub TestDraft2(recip As String, subj As String)
    Dim OlApp As Object
    Dim NS As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim OlMail As Object

    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set NS = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set folder = NS.PickFolder ' save the results of the folder-picker...
    ' MsgBox (TypeName(folder)) ' returns "MAPIFolder

    Set OlMail = OlApp.createitem(0) 'olMailitem = 0
    OlMail.Subject = subj
    OlMail.Recipients.Add (recip)
    OlMail.Move (folder) ' ... and use the saved results of the folder-picker -> runtime error
End Sub
```

Comment: the reason it does not work is that olmail.move needs an outlook-folder as target; as your "Folder" is defined as object, this is not recognized as valid outlook-Folder.
Why are you not using the Microsoft Outlook Object Library in Excel?`Just tested this and seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

This shows how new I am to VBA syntax.

Replacing:

```
OlMail.Move (folder)
```

with

```
OlMail.Move folder
```

fixed the problem.

This is what I believe is going on: **MailItem.Move returns no result, so it uses the non-parentheses syntax.**

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278645

Thus, (folder) is interpreted as an expression, and returns the text value of the folder name inside the parentheses.  Evidence:

```
Dim testobj as Object
Set testobj = (folder) ' fails: Object required

Dim testvar as Variant
testvar = (folder)
MsgBox (VarType(testvar) = vbString) ' returns True
```

So, while `folder` is an object of the correct type, `(folder)` is an expression which evaluates to a string.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just miss the objmail.save before moving it.

and your definitions are a problem for sure:
Change the first lines of your Sub as follows (untested):

```
Sub TestDraft2(recip As String, subj As String)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim NS As Outlook.Namespace 
    Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim OlMail As Outlook.mailitem

    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set NS = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set folder = NS.PickFolder
```

that could help...

Comment: Thank you for your response! That would require early binding, which I'm avoiding so that I can distribute the spreadsheet without requiring special configuration. I'll edit my question, since I should have pointed that out.